# How to use underlaying product permalink in WooCommerce bundled items function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was wondering how to override the default product bundles permalink function. I use the plugin Woocommerce Product bundles for this.

The default function from "class-wc-bundled-item" is this:

```
/**
 * Item permalink.
 *
 * @since  5.5.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_permalink() {
    /**
     * 'woocommerce_bundled_item_permalink' filter.
     *
     * @param  string           $permalink
     * @param  WC_Bundled_Item  $this
     */
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bundled_item_permalink', $this->is_visible() && $this->product->is_visible() ? $this->product->get_permalink() : '', $this );
}
```

I want to override this function in my functions.php file. Unfortunately it returns the permalink of the product bundle and not from the linked (underlaying) product.

This is the code i tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bundled_item_permalink', 'get_bundle_product_permalink' );
function get_bundle_product_permalink() {
    return get_permalink();
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Finally i want to bypass the "is_visible" function from the apply filter. I want the link is always visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', '__return_true' );
```

Try this code snippet to bypass is_visble check

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solving the issue. It returns the permalink of the main bundle product with number "1" after the permalink.

Comment: @Justus remove your hook and use only this

Comment: I just did. The only active rule in my functions.php file is your snippet. ;-)

Comment: It still returns the permalink of the main bundle product with number "1" after the permalink.

Comment: @Justus Update the hook

Comment: Do you have a code example? I am not sure how to update the hook

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
/* Set the visibility function */
function filter_woocommerce_product_is_visible( $visible, $this_get_id ) {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bundled_item_permalink', '__return_true' );
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'filter_woocommerce_product_is_visible', 10, 2 );
```